# setting url in ajax prefilter causes dataType settings in ajax setup to be ignored

Tags: jquery

I am trying to manipulate the ajax url options using a ajax prefilter like shown below, but when the ajax is called with filter, the new url is used but the dataType is ignored, which means no callback parameter is added to the url, and i get a bad request. this only happens when i try to set a new url. the callback is added as it should for instance when i only set new data parameters. also when i try to set the dataType option in the perfilter together with the url, the callback parameter is still not added. am i doing something wrong? thanks a lot for reading this!!

```
    var ajaxItem = {
        setUp: function (a) {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                url: "url1.php?",
                data: {
                    'meta_prefix': 'm_',
                },
                dataType: 'jsonp',      
            });
        }
    };

    var ajaxProd = {
        setUp: function () {
            $.ajaxPrefilter( function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
                options.url = "url2.php?";
    //also when i set dataType here again, the callback parameter is not added to the url
            //options.dataType = 'jsonp'; 
            });
        }
    };
```

Comment: hard to know why you are using global ajax methods without seeing more of your usage code... I suspect you don't want to use globals

Comment: sorry i tried to keep the code as confined as possible here for easier debugging. the thing is that i need to send various requests to different urls and with different data parameters (which the ajaxProd.setUp(requestUrls, paras) takes as its parameters). i want to set those dynamically for each call since i do not want to write a ajax request for each separate call

Comment: try just building a simple object for each type of call without using the ajax global methods

Comment: thanks charlietfl i think you are right. that ajax prefiltering does not work very well

Answer (score 0):

I found a gist that solved a similar problem (I wanted to send JSONP if a plugin was being run on an external domain, so it could retrieve the same data).

Here's the gist:
https://gist.github.com/craveytrain/1028553

My version:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter('json', function(options) {
  // replace with your condition or remove the `if` clause and just return jsonp
  if ( true ) { 
    return 'jsonp';
  }
});
```